# Why isn't the while loop wokring

Tags: python-3.x

```py
package = input("Enter a package designation A,B, C: ")

while package != 'a' or package != 'A' or package != 'b' or package != 'B' or package != 'c' or package != 'C':
    print("Erorr:you didn't enter a valid package")
    package = input("Enter a package designation A,B, C: ")
```

Every time I input the letters a-c or A-C the compiler gets stuck in the while loop even though I continue to re-enter the values and the code say's this as long as the package doesn't equal these values

Comment: Please edit your question. Everything about it is sloppy.

Comment: There is no ``str`` value for which ``package != 'a' or package != 'A'`` (and by extension the rest of the check) can ever be true. Consider which value you *think* satisfies this, and check it against the expression.

Comment: I agree the question isn't great, but straight off your logic is flawed, as your WHILE loop is always True.  Work through it with an 'A'.   That's not equal to 'a', so you get True, your OR has been satisfied and is True, so continue the loop.  You'd need to use AND, but something like while package.upper() not in ["A","B","C"] would be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there a pretty good reason for this.

Let me explain this below so I can make it easy for you.(I hope)

Every time you are giving a letter the condition will be True.
But why is that?

**Let's debug this together:**
`package = input("Enter a package designation A,B, C: ")`

We are giving for an example the letter `"c"`

`package <== "c"`

**And then we are checking the condition for the while loop:**

`package != 'a' or package != 'A' ==> True`

`package != 'b' or package != 'B' ==> True`

`package != 'c' or package != 'C' ==> True` But wait.. how is that even possible?

Well `package != "c" ==> False` but `package != 'C' ==> True`

So what's the condition's outcome? **True**

That's because the or statement returns **True** if one of the conditions is **True**.

That's the reason you are stuck in an endless loop.

**The Solution:**

```
package = input("Enter a package designation A,B, C: ")
letters = "abcABC"

while package not in letters:
    print("Erorr:you didn't enter a valid package")
    package = input("Enter a package designation A,B, C: ")
```

You should know that there are better solutions to this problem but i wanted to go for a simplier approach.

Anyway hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is always `True` due to the `or`s.
Putting all the conditions into one simple conditional statement solves this.

```
package = str(input("Enter a package designation A,B, C: "))
while package.lower() not in ['a','b','c']:
    print("Erorr:you didn't enter a valid package")
    package = str(input("Enter a package designation A,B, C: "))
```